# PHP session is present --- requested page loads yet briefly --- and goes back to index

Tags: php, session

Ok so I'm not really sure how to explain the problem but here goes:

i have a login that gets checked if the input corresponds with the data in my database.
If it does, i create a $_SESSION["login"]. And the user is now logged in.

this session gets created without a problem. So here's my code I use to check if the session is present:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["login"])){
    $_SESSION["denied"]= "You need to be logged in to access this page";
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

now when I go to for instance to my page 'cart' (link located on my index.php page) i put the above code at the beginning of the page, since you need to be logged in to view this page.  However i can see the browser load that page, but nothing happens.  it is as if for a very tiny second I'm at my page 'cart' but that it...

Can anybody help me out with this one.  PHP is mostly a mystery to me.

thanks!

OK, here's an update on the code.  This part is what i put in my 'cart.php

```
<?php 

session_start();
include("inc/database.php");



if(!isset($_SESSION["login"])){
    $_SESSION["denied"]= "You need to be logged in to access this page";
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
    <head>
    <title>Cart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

  testing if the page shows correctly
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my code for my login check

```
<?php

session_start();
include("inc/database.php");
include("inc/clean.php");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $username2=clean($_POST['username2']);
    $password2=clean($_POST['password2']);

    $query=("SELECT *  
            FROM signup
            WHERE username='$username2' 
            AND password='$password2';");

    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    $query2=("SELECT id
              FROM signup
              WHERE username='$username2';");

    $result2=mysql_query($query2);

    while(list($id)=mysql_fetch_row($result2)){
            echo($id);
    }


    if($count == 1){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username2;

        header('location:index.php');
    }else{
    $_SESSION["error"] = "error";
    header('location:index.php');
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post your "cart.php" code? Also, make sure you have session_start() at the beginning of the page

Comment: lol `mystery` .. the code you added here can be called `mystery` too ... can you update with  login side where you created the session variables

Comment: ?  It sounds like it's doing exactly what you want it to do when you are not logged in, namely redirecting back to index.php.  Are you sure you set 'session_start() when you LOG IN and before you set $_SESSION['login']...?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of the `$_SESSION['login']` right before your if statement. If its non existent, then your code is doing exactly what you're specifying it to.

Comment: Also, if you want to redirect, you can `exit();` after setting headers to prevent anything more to be executed while headers are being sent (just in case).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the header instruction, this is the correct one:

```
 header("location: index.php");
```

Probably your code reaches this instruction but the redirection fails.

And of course check the php log and see if erros are reported...